Is there any textbox available which could work like a free textbox and also work as dropdown list in node.js or jQuery
I want to show options on mouse click in textbox like a dropdown list.
And also I could enter my own text in free textbox (If option is not showing into the listing) using node.js or jQuery.
dropdown like this
free text like this
I am new with this technology.
Please help me.

Use Datalist Element. On "save" you could repopulate that <datalist>  with a Unique set of Option Elements using JavaScript - from an array of options values - if needed.
